# Как подождать завершения setTimeout с async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

Есть простая как грабли задача. Три операции - две синхронные, между ними одна асинхронная.
Нужно чтобы асинхронная задача выполнилась **второй по счёту, а не последней**. Конечный результат вычислений должен быть равен единице - 1.
Как этого достичь используя синтаксис **async/await**, **не используя глобальный объект Promise**. Ниже примерное решение, НО неверное.

*Зачем мне это нужно, что это за странный код, какой в этом смысл и т.д. эти вопросы сразу мимо.
Я потратил на эту задачу несколько дней и все к кому я обращался не смогли её решить. Только ради этой задачи я зарегался на этом сайте, так что для меня это важно.*

```
const summarize = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2;
const divide = (num1, num2) => num1/num2;

let x = 2;
let y = 6;
let z = 10;

const calcAsync = async () => {
  x = summarize(x, x);                           // (1шаг) 2 + 2 = 4
  x = await setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y), 1);// (2шаг) ??? должно получится 4 + 6 = 10
  x = divide(x, z);                              // (3шаг) ??? должно получится 10/10 = 1
}

calcAsync();
```

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то в setTimeout передают только имя функции, если указаны ещё и скобки с аргументами, функция срабатывает сразу, без задержек.

Comment: _не используя глобальный объект Promise_ - никак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться тем, что `await` можно применить к `thenable` объекту, а именно объекту с методом `then`.

По аналогии с конструктором `Promise` метод `then` так же принимает два аргумента для `resolve` и `reject`.

```js
const summarize = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2;
const divide = (num1, num2) => num1 / num2;

let x = 2;
let y = 6;
let z = 10;

const calcAsync = async() => {
  x = summarize(x, x); // (1шаг) 2 + 2 = 4
  console.log('(1шаг)', x);
  x = await {
    then(r) {
      setTimeout(() => r(summarize(x, y)), 1)
    }
  }; // (2шаг) ??? должно получится 4 + 6 = 10
  console.log('(2шаг)', x);
  x = divide(x, z); // (3шаг) ??? должно получится 10/10 = 1
  console.log('(3шаг)', x);
}

calcAsync();
```

Comment: Чёрт, зря расписывал всё это. Обидно... Но зато узнал что-то новое :)

Comment: Неплохо, не знал что так можно О_о

Comment: @ДаЁпрстСколькоМожно примите пожалуйста ответ Grundy, чтобы я мог свой удалить :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, зачем удалять-то?

Comment: @Grundy ну ответ ошибочный. Зайдут сюда потом другие и увидят ответ с большим кол-ом голосов и галочкой и ошибочно будут думать что я прав. А я не хочу такое допускать :) Если я не прав, то я умею это признавать)

Comment: @EzioMercer Ок, этот я приму, но ваш удалять не нужно, он тоже очень полезный и объясняет работу таймаутов и промисов.

Comment: @Siberian Хорошо, поправлю тогда свой ответ, вместо удаления раз уже двое настаивают на не удалении :)

Answer (score 7):

Вам надо было обернуть `setTimeout` в [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
const summarize = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2;
const divide = (num1, num2) => num1 / num2;

let x = 2;
let y = 6;
let z = 10;

const calcAsync = async() => {
  x = summarize(x, x);
  
  console.log(1, x);
  
  x = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(summarize(x, y)));
  });
  
  console.log(2, x);
  
  x = divide(x, z);
  
  console.log(3, x);
}

calcAsync();
```

### Объяснение того, почему нельзя обойтись без `Promise`:

P.S. Формально это утверждение - не верное. Как показал [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424772/385375) достаточно заменить `Promise` на самый обычный `thenable` объект (объект у которого есть метод `then`) и в этом случае всё будет работать точно так же как и с `Promise`. Но этот ответ даст вам понимание того, почему не поможет `await`-тить или оборачивать в `async` ф-ию `setTimeout`

Рассмотрим этот кусок кода:

```
const calcAsync = async () => {
  x = summarize(x, x);
  x = await setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y), 1);
  x = divide(x, z);
}
```

Т.к. `async/await` возвращает и работает `Promise`, то давайте переведём этот кусок кода на язык `Promise`-ов:

```
const calcAsync = () => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
      x = summarize(x, x);

      return setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y), 1);
    })
    .then(function (handleResolved) {
      x = handleResolved;
      x = divide(x, z);
    });
};
```

И так нас интересует строка с `setTimeout`. В [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises) сказано, что `then` на вход получит от `Promise`-а 2 аргумента - это `handleResolved` и `handleRejected` и так же [сказано](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), что он сам тоже вернёт `Promise`. Нас интересует, только `handleResolved`, потому дальше `handleRejected` будет опущен. И так второй `then` на вход получит возращаемое значение `setTimeout` - это число [timeoutID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#return_value) и абсолютно не важно что какая ф-ия будет запущена и когда она будет запущена. Следовательно во втором `then`, где строчка `x = handleResolved` в `x` будет записано число `timeoutID` и дальнейшие вычисления будут проводиться именно с этим значением. Что важно это число каждый раз будет разным, и перезапуская один и тот же код в одной сессии вы будете получать разные значения

Демо код (специально убрал `x = await...`, чтобы не подумали, что всё из-за того что в `x` что-то записывается):

```js
const summarize = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2;
const divide = (num1, num2) => num1 / num2;

let x = 2;
let y = 6;
let z = 10;

const calcAsync = async() => {
  x = summarize(x, x);

  console.log(await setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y)));
  console.log(await setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y)));
  console.log(await setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y)));
  console.log(await setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y)));

  x = divide(x, z);
}

calcAsync();
```

Нам же надо чтобы в `x` во втором `then` попало значение `summarize(x, y)`.

Автором был предложен вариант, обернуть `setTimeout` в `async` ф-ию т.к. `async` нам возвращает `Promise`. Замечу, что писать в обёртке что-то типа `return await setTimeout` будет так же бесполезно как и если без обёртки. Давайте посмотрим, что будет в этом случае:

```
const asyncSum = async () => {return setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y), 1)}

const calcAsync = async() => {
  x = summarize(x, x);
  
  x = await asyncSum();
  
  x = divide(x, z);
}
```

переписвая это на язык `Promise`-ов получим:

```
const asyncSum = () => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y), 1);
  });
};

const calcAsync = () => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
      x = summarize(x, x);

      return asyncSum();
    })
    .then(function (handleResolved) {
      x = handleResolved;
      x = divide(x, z);
    });
};
```

Теперь можем спокойно подставить результат нашей ф-ии `asyncSum` туда, где он вызывается и получаем:

```
const calcAsync = () => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
      x = summarize(x, x);

      return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
        return setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y), 1);
      });
    })
    .then(function (handleResolved) {
      x = handleResolved;
      x = divide(x, z);
    });
};
```

И что мы видим? Мы опять отправляем в `handleResolved` наш `timeoutID`. Потому обёртки тут тоже не помогут отправить само значение `summarize(x, y)`

Теперь, когда разобрались, почему мы не можем ни `await`-тить ни оборачивать в `async` ф-ии наш `setTimeout`, посмотрим как нам помогает обёртка `Promise`-ом:

```
const calcAsync = async() => {
  x = summarize(x, x);
  
  x = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(summarize(x, y)), 1);
  });
  
  x = divide(x, z);
}
```

опять переписываем на язык `Promise`-ов и получаем:

```
const calcAsync = () => {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
      x = summarize(x, x);

      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(summarize(x, y)), 1);
      });
    })
    .then(function (handleResolved) {
      x = handleResolved;
      x = divide(x, z);
    });
};
```

Теперь видно, что мы явно в `handleResolved` передаём значение ф-ии `summarize(x, y)` в строке `resolve(summarize(x, y))`. Тут уже дело в том, что пока не будет вызыван/отработан `resolve` последующий `then` будет ждать, сколько бы это не заняло времени

P.S В [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description) сказано, что этот кусок кода:

```
async function foo() {
   return 1
}
```

похоже на:

```
function foo() {
   return Promise.resolve(1)
}
```

но я переписывал это как:

```
function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return 1;
  });
}
```

в самих рассуждениях и примерах это ни на что не влияет. Вся логика будет точно такой же, если переписывать как показано в документации, но чтобы не переключаться постоянно между методами `resolve` и `then`, решил что, если всегда будет `then`, то будет меньше путаницы и это позволит лучше понять что происходит. Надеюсь смог добиться этого :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137393/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer----settimeout--async-a).

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> await setTimeout(() => summarize(x, y), 1);
> ```

1. `setTimeout` возвращает id таймера сразу, никакого толка от `await` тут нет.
2. Да и вообще, результат вызова `summarize` не используется.
3. 1ms - это странно. Скорее всего тут и нулю или отсутствующему аргументу неплохо.

Надо так:

```
x = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0, summarize(x, y)))
```

Хотя в любом случае вся эта конструкция предполагает, что результат известен синхронно, так что непонятно, нафига она сделась.

> Нужно только с async/await без Promise, без then(), код должен быть максимально похож на синхронный.

Так не пойдёт: `await` работает именно с `then`.

Comment: А можно ли решить эту задачу вот как-то так:
async function foo () {
  return 'Hello, world';
}

(async function () {
  const text = await foo();
  console.log(text); // Hello, world
})();
???

Comment: 1ms это для примера, можно поставить что угодно.

Comment: @ДаЁпрстСколькоМожно, а где в этом решении таймаут?

Comment: таймаута нету, я просто хотел показать сам подход к решению, без `new Promise`