# Пользовательский prompt

Tags: javascript, promise, асинхронность

#### Описание

После [небольшой дискуссии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480407/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-alert-confirm-prompt#comment2651595_1480407) решил создать собственную версию `window.prompt()`. Моя версия выглядит так:

```js
class Manager {
  static async prompt(message) {
    const dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement(`dialog`));
    dialog.appendChild(document.createElement(`span`)).innerText = message;
    const input = dialog.appendChild(document.createElement(`input`));
    input.type = `text`;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      dialog.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
        if (event.target == dialog) {
          resolve(input.value);
          dialog.remove()
        }
      });
    });
    dialog.showModal();
    return await promise;
  }
}

document.write(Manager.prompt(`Input text`));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

body * {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

dialog {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

input {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  padding: 8px;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%)
}
```

После ввода надо нажимать вне окна и значение передается. Проблема в том, что, чтобы я не делал, где бы я не пимал `async` и `await` передается `Promise<String>`.

#### Вопрос

Но что мне делать, чтобы передавалась просто `String`, как во встроенной версии.

#### Уточнение

Возможно проблема в том, что я неправильно реализовал `async` и `await`, поскольку немного работал с ними и не все тонкости знаю. Так что с удовольствием приму и статью где, есть решение моей проблемы и объяснения - почему так происходит.

Comment: Зачем вам тут аснхронность? Я не вижу ничего что требует асинхронности тут

Comment: @EzioMercer ну так значение возвращается не сразу, а когда пользователь нажмет вне окна. Можете показать правильное решение без асинхронности?

Comment: Ну не то чтобы без асинхронности, но вам просто надо навестить правильно слушателей, которые сами по себе асинхронны (я уже говорил вам об этом). Вам не нужно самому прописывать асинхронность

Comment: @EzioMercer вот в этом и проблема. Думаю, я не совсем понимаю как работает асинхронность и искал по поводу этого примеры в интернете. Из 5 страниц Google только примеры как сериализовать асинхронность с `fetch`, с новой `Promise` и.т.д., но нигде нет ни один единственный случай с нажатием кнопки или какого-то другого обработчика.

Comment: Надо не по гуглу искать, а надо в [доках прочитать](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) :) Извините, но это не маленькая тема, чтобы тут расписывать подробно

Comment: @Grundy ответ к которому вы оставили ссылку, не решает этот вопрос. В данном вопросе я именно таким способом и пытаюсь решить и не получается. К тому же в вашем вопросе используется ajax, jquery и.т.д., а тут библиотеки не используются. Так что вопрос не дубликат.

Comment: На самом деле неважно что вы используете библиотеку или `fetch`, в указанном @Grundy дубликате, в ответах достатоточно подробно описано, почему нельзя работать с асинхронными функциями т.к. хотите вы. И там даны множество обходных путей. Так что вопрос как по мне закрыт правильным дубликатом

Comment: @eccs0103, решает, достаточно добавить `await` и получишь нужно значение, о чем и указано в дубликате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вашу задачу решить простым колбеком, чтобы не мучаться с асинхронностью:

```js
class Manager {
  static prompt(message, callBack) {
    const dialog = document.createElement('dialog');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    
    span.innerText = message;
    input.type = 'text';
    
    dialog.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (event.target !== dialog) return;

      callBack(input.value);
      dialog.remove();
    });
    
    dialog.append(span, input);
    document.body.append(dialog);
    
    dialog.showModal();
  }
}

Manager.prompt('Input text', (ans) => document.write(ans));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  //background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  //color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

body * {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

dialog {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

input {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  padding: 8px;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%)
}
```

Как только вы начнёте писать `async` и/или использовать `Promise`-ы, там надо будет всё это дело вызывать в асинхронной функции или использовать синтаксис `then`. Про подробное объяснение, почему без этого нельзя обойтись, можете почитать [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424364/385375)

Comment: Я и использовал в проекте тот метод который вы описали выше. Вопрос о другом. Это попытка создать точь в точь prompt() исправляя ее недостатки, а не обойти их.

Comment: @eccs0103, не получится так. Как только вы начнёте писать `async` и/или использовать `Promise`-ы, там надо будет всё это дело вызывать в асинхронной функции или использовать синтаксис `then`. Про подробное объяснение, почему без этого нельзя обойтись, можете почитать [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424364/385375)

Comment: О том, что после `async` придётся обязательно использовать `await` еще и снаружи я и не имел понятия, так как мой второй рабочий язык является C# и там эта конструкция прекрасно работает. Вот я и думал, что не смотря различия этих языков они и не редко похожи, поэтому и тут должно работать. Ваш комментарий дополняет ответ. Вставьте его в ответ и я приму его.

Comment: @eccs0103, в c# ты точно также не можешь _получить значение_ `без await`

Comment: @Grundy я не говорю без `await`, я буду использовать `await` внутри функции и она вернет не `Task<String>`, а `String` как указано в примере.

Comment: @Grundy а в JS `async` функция вернет с `await` или без, все равно получаешь `Promise<...>`

Comment: @eccs0103, точно также как и в c# - тут у них нет никакой разницы.

Comment: @Grundy проверил примером - вы правы! Чёт я запутался. :) А тогда как работает `window.prompt()` который является асинхронной функцией, но возвращает не `Promise`?

Comment: @eccs0103 А кто сказал, что `window.promt()` - асинхронный?

Comment: @eccs0103, браузерный prompt - это синхронная функция, которая блокирует выполнение всех скриптов, во время своего выполнения

Comment: EzioMercer, @Grundy понял, благодарю за объяснения (и терпение :) ) .